# Quick way to temporarily disable compiz and gnome shortcuts

Tags: gnome, compiz, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Compiz and Gnome have many keyboard shortcuts. Examples are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for locking the session or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> for switching workspaces. Often they overwrite shortcuts in applications. It would be nice to have a way to temporarily disable these system shortcuts to make way for application shortcuts. Best thing would be to have a shortcut for doing so. :)

Any solutions, ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to **disable** and **enable** individual shortcut-keys in Compiz:

Assign these two commands to hotkeys, or just run them in the terminal (either asis, or in scripts).

You can setup your shortcut-keys via "Keyboard Shortcuts" in the Preferences Menu... (I use `xbindkeys`.. It has finer control over wihch keys you can use. eg Numlock on/off makes a difference.)

Turn enable the shortcut-key for: *Zoom Specific Level 1*:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz/plugins/ezoom/allscreens/options/zoom_specific_1_key --type string "<Shift><Control>Return"
```

Turn disable the shortcut-key for: *Zoom Specific Level 1*:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz/plugins/ezoom/allscreens/options/zoom_specific_1_key --type string "Disabled"
```

If there are many hotkeys, just make two scripts: one for **on**, and the other for **off**

You can find all the Compiz keys in Gconf Editor:  `gconf-editorenter code here

Comment: This looks like a very promising solution. I will try this. Maybe you know a (semi) automatic way to extract the current settings into the script? Or at least a file where I can read them without having to browse through the compiz setting manager.

Comment: Actually it works and solves all my problems in a very customizable way. Thank you!

Comment: @ziggystar... You're welcome... To list all keys and values: `gconftool-2 --recursive-list /apps/compiz`  ... to get more info: `info gconftool-2`

Answer (score 4):

To disable compiz temporarily, replace it with metacity, that's the other window manager/decorator.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and run `metacity --replace`

To restore compiz, run `compiz --replace`

Of course, after logging off and in, or rebooting your computer, compiz will be used as the window manager (since this command disables it temporarily).

I use it quite often, so I've even bound it to a launcher in the gnome panel.

Comment: For anyone runnint those commands in the terminal, you should follow the command by an & ...see [http://askubuntu.com/questions/12682/why-does-metacity-replace-hang-my-system-but-metacity-replace-is-fine)

Comment: This is a rather bold way of disabling the compiz shortcuts. Still, some (like ctrl+alt+arrows) remain active. Still, the switch is quick and it doesn't need any prerequisites.