# Alt+Q close window doesn't work

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

I'd really like to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to close windows as it fits with my Mac-like muscle memory. However, I can't get this combination to work.

I've changed it in the Keyboard settings under shortcuts and also changed all the instances of close window I can find in gconf editor.

I'm using cinnamon and my alt key works for all manner of other things (like switching windows).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

press and hold the <kbd>super</kbd> key to check if **Closes Current Window** is bound to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

If you can see your shortcut set there, try to [disable compiz shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17315/quick-way-to-temporarily-disable-compiz-and-gnome-shortcuts)

Comment: I'm not using compiz and holding down <kbd>super</kbd> does nothing. I can try this on a vanilla install though (but I don't think it works). I saw somewhere that it could be because <kbd>ALT</kbd> doesn't send escape sequences but that sounds a little odd.